# How do component dependencies work in A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to understand how dependencies work in A-frame components as it does not seem to work the way I thought it did.

**The scenario**, I am trying to create a sort of "mothership" component to store global info that can be accessed from different components at different stages on an experience. To do so I attach a component to the `a-scene` and I then attach a "satellite" component to a child entity of that scene.

**The problem** is that on load the mothership component does not seem to be initialised in time for its properties to be accessed. I thought if I added the mothership component as a `dependency` of the satellite component it would wait for it to be initialised but it does not seem to work.

See below the components;

```
//the mothership component
 AFRAME.registerComponent('mothership', {  
        schema: {
          testString: {type: 'string', default: 'Working'},
        },
        init: function(){
        },
 }),

//the satellite component
  AFRAME.registerComponent('satellite', {     
        
        dependencies: ['mothership'],
        
        init: function(){
          
          var mother = this.el.sceneEl
          var self = this.el

          var message = mother.getAttribute('mothership').testString
          //to demonstrate problem
          self.setAttribute('value', message)
          console.log(message)
          //-> undefined
       
        },
 })
```

And the HTML

```
 <a-scene mothership>
      <a-text 
        satellite
        position="0 1.6 -3"
        color="black"
        align="center"
        value="">
      </a-text>
 </a-scene>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbp15fqv/1/) of this example which shows how it is not working, the value of `testString` is `undefined`.

I have managed to make the connection between these 2 components work by adding an `eventListener` to the satellite component that waits for the mothership's `loaded` event. See below example and fiddle.

```
      //the mothership component
      AFRAME.registerComponent('mothership', {  
        schema: {
          testString: {type: 'string', default: 'Working'},
        },
        init: function(){
        },
      }),
    
      //the satellite component
      AFRAME.registerComponent('satellite', {     
        
        dependencies: ['mothership'],
        
        init: function(){
          
          var mother = this.el.sceneEl
          var self = this.el
    
          //wait for mothership to be loaded
          mother.addEventListener('loaded', function(){
            var message = mother.getAttribute('mothership').testString
            //to demonstrate problem
            self.setAttribute('value', message)
            console.log(message)
          })
          
        },
      })
```

With the same HTML as original example. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbp15fqv/6/) of that one which works as I expected.

So does `dependencies` not mean wait for the specified component(s) to be loaded/initialised? Or am I doing something wrong? I can get around this using the eventListener if necessary but I would like to understand this better and if there is better way to achieve this.

Any advice appreciated as ever and let me know if you need any more information to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component dependencies apply to components on the same entity, not across entities like your satellite / mothership component example. Using the loaded event as you did is the way to go.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining that, much appreciated.